# Existe alguma forma automática de criar um atalho de uma página WEB em dispositivos android ou IOS?

Tags: aplicação-web

Estou precisando criar um crachá para participantes de eventos, já tenha essa aplicação WEB, mas seria interessante que desse para salvar um atalho dessa página no menu do celular.

O problema está na usabilidade, pois a maioria não saberá criar o atalho.

Alguém consegue dar um norte?

Hoje o sistema interno é feito em PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode tentar fazer um botão para acionar o javascript `window.external.AddFavorite("url", "title");`

Comment: Olá Antônio. A intenção de ajudar é legal, mas aqui no site sempre deve focar em ler as documentações e fornecer respostas testadas. Para resumir esse código não funciona na maioria dos navegadores, fora que window.external está obsoleto e por isso o seu uso deve ser desencorajado. Segu documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/external

Comment: Entendi obrigado pela orientação